# Google sheets tips

Tags: google-sheets

In a spreadsheet of 40,000 rows, I want to select the first 2,500 rows to copy them to another sheet. The only way I've seen is to select the first row and tediously scroll the "dot" down to include all 2,500 rows. kindly give solution for this.

kindly give solution for this.

Comment: Use `QUERY()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `QUERY` function with the `limit` clause:

```cpp
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:A,"limit 2500",0)
```

If you want to select the next 2500 rows, you can use the `offset` clause. The following formula for example returns 2500 rows starting from row 2501:

```cpp
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:A,"limit 2500 offset 2500",0)
```

In general, this formula returns `n` rows starting from row `m`. If `m` is 1, the `offset` clause can be omitted.

```cpp
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:A,"limit n offset m-1",0)
```